# curl: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate

Tags: certificate

certificate is very new to me, I came to this question because `docker pull` failed. Then I check the url with wget and curl, they all describe certificate is somehow wrong.

**docker error**

Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for *.cwzpvo.com, not registry-1.docker.io

**curl error**

```
curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
```

curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.

**wget error**

```
wget https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
```

--2019-11-23 18:24:19--  https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
Resolving registry-1.docker.io (registry-1.docker.io)... 34.205.207.96
Connecting to registry-1.docker.io (registry-1.docker.io)|34.205.207.96|:443... connected.
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
    requested host name 'registry-1.docker.io'.
To connect to registry-1.docker.io insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

My final goal is to get docker pull working

Comment: Either you are getting redirected silently to a captive portal (a network login page e.g.) or someone actively tries to hijack the connection. Certificates show you that you connected to the requested domain.

Comment: This could also be some kind of https proxy for a whole network, but if the `cwzpvo` domain name isn't familiar to you and you're not expecting some kind of network proxy or captive portal, then I'd lean more toward this potentially being something malicious.  What kind of network are you on?